# Which program/language was used to plot the point at infinity of these images? (See the images)

Tags: elliptic-curves

The code of the first image was provided by *Squeamish Ossifrage* in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70526/65803). In wich language/program was plot? In JavaScript or GeoGebra?

[image]

Also, I found in YouTube the image below with the *point at infinity* (north pole) plot in a *projective plane* using *stereographic projection*. The YouTube channel is [Trustica](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-RuV9nXyysbH0kB4pVqZTg). I copy the picture from the [website](https://trustica.cz/en/2018/04/05/elliptic-curves-point-at-infinity-revisited/) attached in the description of the video. What language/program was used? Any ideas?

[image: Elliptic c]

I tried to replicate the graphs in Mathematica but failed.

Comment: It is Asymptote as given in the asnwer `Appendix A: Asymptote code for affine elliptic curve plot`

Comment: For the second image: I saw the Trustica videos, too, and wanted to plot it myself. I wrote them, but never got an answer. I just assume that they did it with SageMath. If you find the sourcecode please post it here! I would love to plot it myself, too!

Comment: Thank you @kelalaka! I never hear about that language.

Comment: [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87545/18298), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582244/62865) some other examples.

Comment: @Titanlord It should be asymptote, too, at least you can make it.