# ECDH public keys restrictions

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, elliptic-curve-generation

I know that Bob can calculate the shared DH key without knowing the private key. If he sends to Alice a public key = 1, then the the DH key would be 1.

Can i achieve something like this in ECDH? where Bob can calculate the shared key without knowing the private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly, just send the identity element $\mathcal{O}$ as the public key.

Alice must be a fool to not [validate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66296/18298) the public key to fall into this trap. The first rule is to check that $P \neq \mathcal{O}$

---

**Update per user's [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89349/ecdh-public-keys-restrictions/89350?noredirect=1#comment197261_89350)**

> How can i find the identity element of curve 25519?

The identity of some curves like Curve25519 is the point of infinity ( represented as $\mathcal{O} \text { or } \infty$) and this can't be represented in the affine coordinates. We need to use [projective coordinate systems](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66296/18298).

We took the Curve25519 equation $$y^2 = x^3 + 486662 x^2 + x$$ and convert it into homogeneous equation $$Y^2 Z - X^3 - 486662 X^2 Z - X Z^2$$

Now the points are triple $(X:Y:Z)$ where actually a point now represent a line $(\lambda X:\lambda Y: \lambda Z)$

**The point at infinity** is $(0:1:0)$ and this cannot be treated as an affine point.

Any affine point $(x,y)$ can be turned into homogenous by $(x:y:1)$ and any homogenous point other than the infinity $(X:Y:Z)$ can be turned back with $(X/Z,Y/Z)$.

Comment: Another potential defense is simply not have a 'bits-on-the-wire' representation that you interpret as $\mathcal{O}$; hence you cannot possibly receive it...

Comment: @poncho any library does this?

Comment: Well, if you're conforming to a spec that specifies formats (such as TLS or IKE), and they don't specify how you would transmit $\mathcal{O}$ (which TLS/IKE doesn't for P256), hence they'd have to do it.

Comment: @kelalaka How can i find the identity element of curve 25519?

Comment: @AshrafYassin updated the asnwer.

Comment: @kelalaka so Bob needs to send A=(0,1), and assuming Alice doesn't check the public key, what will be the shared key?

Comment: in short : HASH(0)